# Jupyter notebook files not written to host when using mounted Docker volume (-v option)

Tags: docker, macos, jupyter-notebook

I am developing notebooks in a JupyterLab Docker container running on MacOS Sonoma 14.0.

I want the notebook files (*.ipynb) to persist on disk when the container has stopped.

I have added a `-v` option to the docker run command but the notebooks never appear in the mounted volume when they are saved.

Here is what I have tried so far:

1. I have created an empty directory on the host where the notebook files should be stored. I have given this directory full permissions (777) and used the user ID of 1000 as the directory owner. User ID 1000 is the ID of the user named "joyvan" which is the user that runs the Jupyter server in the Docker container.

```
~/pyspark_notebooks/examples % ll -ah `pwd`
total 0
drwxrwxrwx  2 1000    staff    64B Oct 31 16:45 .
drwxr-xr-x  4 jadams  staff   128B Oct 31 17:59 ..
```

2. The directory was added to the list of shared file resources in Docker desktop settings.
3. I ran the Docker container using a -v option to mount a volume. I mounted this to the location where I assume the notebook files are written by default, `/home/joyvan/work`.

```
docker run -p 8889:8888 \
-v /Users/jadams/pyspark_notebooks/examples:/home/joyvan/work \
jupyter/pyspark-notebook
```

I've also tried using `/home/joyvan` as the container's mount point. I have tried running as the root user and also setting environment variables such as `-e NB_UID=1000 -e CHOWN_HOME=yes`, but nothing gives. I save one notebook in the main directory and another in the work directory in the left side panel, and when I open a console I can see the files just fine:

```
(base) jovyan@116f56a93bbe:~$ ls
ex1.ipynb  work
(base) jovyan@116f56a93bbe:~$ ls work/
ex2.ipynb
```

Those files never appear in the host's mounted volume folder as expected:

```
~/pyspark_notebooks/examples % ll -ah
total 0
drwxrwxrwx  2 1000    staff    64B Oct 31 16:45 .
drwxr-xr-x  4 jadams  staff   128B Oct 31 17:59 ..
```

Finally, I restarted the Docker Desktop application and tried it all again, with no improvement.

Answer (score 0):

So I misspelled "jovyan" as "joyvan". Once this was rectified everything worked as advertised.